# Using switch statement with 5 cases within a for loop. How do I save case statementss to a database?

Tags: switch-statement

I am passing several strings ($cu1, $cu2, $us1, $us2,etc.)to another page where I use a switch statement to provide standard strings ( a, b, c, d, e ) for saving to a database (cards)  and table (results)

I'm not sure how/where to enter the "$sql=" code for saving the data.  It seems to be redundant to enter the code for each case statement. I've thought about using an include statement for each statement, and have also thought about using the db code after the switch statement but within the for loop.  What would be the best practice and code?

```
for($i=1; $i<14; $i++)   {
    switch($i) {
         case '1':  $a=$cu1; $b=$us1;  $c=$draw1;  $d= $yn1;  $e= $acct_id1;  echo "$e  _ $a  _  $b _ $c _ $d <br>"; break;
         case '2':  $a=$cu2; $b=$us2;  $c=$draw2;  $d= $yn2;  $e= $acct_id2; echo "$e  _ $a  _  $b _ $c _ $d <br>";  break;
    }  // close switch
}  // close for
```